# How to find duplicated CSS code in a folder(with several css files)?

Tags: css, code-duplication

i am looking for a solution to remove duplicated css from different css files a folder. I have found the following solution but this works in a single css file.

*Here are the steps to install and find the duplicated CSS classes:

1. Go to extensions tab (Ctrl + Shift+ X).
2. Search with “DupChecker” and install it.
3. Go to the CSS file. Type (Ctrl + Shift + P) and search
   with “check duplicates with regex match” and select it.
   4.Paste this
   regex ^. [\w-\s.>:,[]*=]+{ and hit Enter.*

In our case there are multiple css files(in a project called "New_Theme") which contains same css properties like:

```
h1{
color:#3B4045
}
```

There are online tool like diffchecker but for more than 10+ files it is not easy to find the duplicated line. Any suggestion

Comment: It's easy to do it with Unix command-line tools such as `grep` and `find`. You can install these tools on Windows with [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com), or WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux). If you're fine with this solution, I'll post an answer.

Comment: @DannyNiu please post your answer

Answer (score 1):

In the following example codes, angle brackets are meant to be filled with actual keywords that you'd like to search for, as well as the paths in which you want to search from.

```
find <project-directory> \( -iname \*.css -o -iname \*.html -o -iname \*.htm \) -exec grep -C 3 -F -i <keywords> {} +
```

Here, I used `-iname` option for `find` and `-i` option for `grep` to request case-insensitive search; `-C` specifies that we want 3 lines of context (this option is non-standard, but widely supported); the `-F` option is meant to turn off regular expression search, as different programs often have different syntax for their regex, `grep` supports 2 different regular expression syntaxes, the basic one without specifying any upper-case flags, and a extended one with `-E` flag (instead of `-F`).

Answer (score 0):

if you just want a tool to find duplicates in a lot of files/folders, atom and VS code have solution for you, its called global search and am not sure about atom, but on vs code you can press `Ctrl + Shift + F` and search tags globally in your opened folders

Comment: yeah by using global search i can search a class and find if it exist in multiple finds but the problem is that i dont know which classes are duplicated. I need a tool which compare all these find and show me the duplicated css.